# system wallpaper should change through service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, wallpaper

my application requires a service that changes the system wallpaper in a particular time interval how should I implement this, please help???

Comment: good question, this interesting for me too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your service class

```
class WallpaperService extends IntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Timer progressTimer = new Timer();
        timeTask = new ProgressTimerTask();
        progressTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timeTask, 0, 1000);
    }

    private class ProgressTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int currenMinutes = 0; // set your time here
                    changeWallpapers(currentMinutes);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void changeWallpapers(int minutes) {
        if(minutes == 1)
            layout.setBackGround(Color.RED);
        if(minutes == 2)
            layout.setBackGround(Color.BLUE);
    }
}
```

}

And then call your service Intent where your want

Answer (score -1):

Well, I have implemented this function. I register an Alarm in the system and connect it to a BroadcastReceiver. When the BroadcastReceiver is triggered, in the OnReceive() method, you can set a wallpaper for the system.

Comment: The reason I downvoted @Huang's Answer is, if you trigger alarm again & again every minute or few hours or even seconds i.e the Alarm is triggered again & again in a short interval & your App is published on Store then you will get a "BAD BEHAVIOR" flag on your App in your Developer Console... Use a Service instead! :)