# How to change android device wallpaper programmatically under regular intervals?

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

How I need it to work,

1. It should change irrespective of the device having an internet connection or  not.
2. It should change every one minute or 20 seconds.
3. Should work even if the app is killed.

The images to be used will be in the device.
I was able to change the device wallpaper by using android wallpaper manager.
The method I chose was to trigger a service using Alarm manager. But the problem is that ever since Android OS introduced doze mode. The alarm gets triggered delayed.Thus the wallpaper changes not on the expected intervals.

I tried searching online about alarm manager,It seems like Alarm manager wont be triggered on short intervals without a delay.

Is there a better way to meet my requirement or if not what am I doing wrong here,Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to create a service class and change the wallpaper on a timer task.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926194/system-wallpaper-should-change-through-service) does provide some insight on how to achieve this.